# Do two arrays of the same size (and length) have same element offsets?

Tags: c++, arrays

The C++ standard seems to be a bit laconic about arrays.

Let's assume that I have two distinct data types: `T1` and `T2`. I create arrays of each of them, with both arrays being of the same length `N`; so I have `T1[N]` and `T2[N]`.

Now, does `sizeof(T1[N]) == sizeof(T2[N])` imply that the successive elements of both arrays will have the same offsets?

Or, in a more practical form: if I (handling the alignment issues) cast a `char[sizeof(T1[N])]` both to `T1*` and to `T2*`, is it guaranteed that `T1[0]` and `T2[1]` will not overlap, and the other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Arrays do not have any padding or alignment on the ends, and thus `sizeof(T1[N])` always equals `sizeof(T1) * N`.

Knowing this, we know that `sizeof(T1[N]) == sizeof(T2[N])` implies `sizeof(T1) == sizeof(T2)` (cancel the `N` on both sides). Additionally arrays must be contiguous, there is no alignment or padding inside of the array. Thus the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Hmm, the implication you've made seems to imply that classes always have padding necessary for the following class in the array to be correctly aligned; am I right?

Comment: @MichałGórny: it doesn't necessarily imply it, but it is a common optimization, yes.

Comment: if it doesn't imply it, does that mean that `T1[1]` may not have correct alignment or am I missing something?

Comment: @MichałGórny: yes. AFAIK the standard doesn't require `T1[1]` to be on a word boundary. But since this is highly preferable, many compilers add padding to the type.

Comment: This is misleading. `t1[1]` must be properly aligned for type `T1`, but the compiler is permitted to make the required alignment for type `T1` simply 1. If the compiler makes the required alignment 4 (as an example), then `t1[1]` must be properly aligned, and the only way to do that is to make `sizeof(T1)` a multiple of 4, in other words, include padding if required.

Comment: I think it's fairly straight-forward: Every object has a notion of *alignment*, no matter whether it is a complete object or a subobject, and every object is allocated so as to meet those requirements. This gives you, recursively, constraints on how classes and arrays are laid out. The only thing you may be allowed is to *change* the alignment of a type (say an `int`), if your compiler allows you to do so.

Comment: To put it another way, when forming `T1[2]` the type might need padding to get the correct alignment for the second element. And though `T1[1]` might get away without it, no compiler cares to make this difference.

Comment: To sum up, I can assume that having `T[N]` properly aligned I will have the whole array properly aligned and I don't have to do any scary things to ensure that?